# How to convert newlines from CRLF to LF while creating Python sdist?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

I'd like to use Windows as my main development platform, but at the same time generate sdist tarballs with LF newlines.

Is there a way to keep CRLF-s in my working directory and turn them automatically to LF-s while doing `python setup.py sdist` ?

Where are all `sdist` options documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no simple way to do it. You have to write some code and I'm not sure it'd be easy.

`sdist` is a command of `distutils` and documented at https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html